# JAVA "cannot be cast to java.lang.String"

Tags: java

I am trying to create a list and output my array of books to it and have the user be able to click one of the books to rent it. The list works and it outputs all of the books however when I click a book and select OK it gives me the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Books cannot be cast to java.lang.String". Could someone explain to me what this error is and how I can fix it?

```
public static void CustomerBooks() throws IOException {
    Object[] Menu = {
            "Option1",
            "Option2",
            "Option3",
            "Option4"
    };
    String userChoice = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Welcome", "Book Menu", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, Menu, null);
    if (userChoice.equals("Option1")) {} else if (userChoice.equals("Option2")) {
        File myFile = new File("books.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);
        Books[] bookArray = new Books[200];
        String str;
        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            str = inputFile.nextLine();
            String[] myData = str.split("#");
            Books.addBook(bookArray, Books.getBookCount(), myData[0], myData[1], myData[2]);
        }
        inputFile.close();
        String userChoice1 = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Books List", "Books", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, bookArray, null);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You chose: " + userChoice1); {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please take the time to indent your code appropriately and remove excessive vertical whitespace. The code is *much* harder to read than it needs to be at the moment. I'd also suggest reducing it to a [mcve]. Fundamentally, it sounds like you're trying to cast a reference to an object of type `Book` to `String`, and that's just not going to work.

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: Books cannot be cast to java.lang.String` I assume that this exception occurs in another part of your code... a stacktrace would help.

Comment: `if (userChoice.equals("Option1")) {} else if (userChoice.equals("Option2")) {` Just drop the first condition, it is redundant: `if (userChoice.equals("Option2")) {`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I reproduced the same behavior

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Book[] ani = new Book[]{new Book(), new Book()};
    String usi = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Books", "Books", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, ani, null);
}
```

---

Do not forget one thing, [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/javax/swing/JOptionPane.java#JOptionPane.showInternalInputDialog%28java.awt.Component%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cint%2Cjavax.swing.Icon%2Cjava.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cjava.lang.Object%29) `Overload` of `showInputDialog` returns the choosen Object (here a `Book`) from the array passed in the parameters.

You certainly want to assign `toString()` or `getName()` from the returned `Object`

---

### Solution

```
Book tmp = (Book) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Books", "Books", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, ani, null);
String userChoice = tmp.getName();
String userChoice2 = tmp.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a `toString()` method available in java which can be called on any object. But if you want to get an appropriate behavior of this method based on the characteristics of your `Book`, you should override it like in the Ibukun's answer.

**Casting** concept is used to get a more specific type of an Object. So since the book is not an `instanceof` the `String` you get a `ClassCastException` at run time.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what the problem is, you didn't post your `Book` Class.
In General, every class has a `toString()` function inbuilt, but this may not necessarily be suited for your class. 
I suggest to override the `toString()` function in your `Book` class.
Something like this.

```
@override
public String toString(){
  // assign result to your intended string
  return result;
}
```